# Download public Google Spreadsheet in VBS using Task Scheduler

Tags: google-sheets, vbscript, download, windows-server-2008, windows-task-scheduler

My vbscript: *saveGSheet.vbs* (to download sheet) works fine when **manually** run. I woud like to automat this, but an automatic task will NOT download the file.

> **How to run this in Task Scheduler?** On Windows Server 2008.

### Task Scheduler - settings:

- Action: Run program: *saveGSheet.bat* with code:
  `c:\Windows\SysWOW64\cscript saveGSheet.vbs`
- Run task as LOCAL SERVICE
- Run task when **NOT LOGGED IN**

### Tried already:

- Run with highest privileges does not help
- creating "Desktop" folders does not help
- "Log on as a batch job" does not help

### Possible reasons:

Not logged in means objects doesnt work properly - possibly needs to be run in interactive mode like MS Excel? I do not understand what in my script needs to be run interactive (logged in)?

- "MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0"
- "ADODB.Stream"

### Vbscript:

```
' Set your settings
strFileURL = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1B5jBWGHT1dGKCwE9KLTlFsyymNCc1s4AH1LcFQOcwqQ/export?format=xlsx"
strHDLocation = "C:\file.xlsx"

' Fetch the file
Set objXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0")

objXMLHTTP.open "GET", strFileURL, false
objXMLHTTP.send()

'Response 200 is OK, now download sheet
If objXMLHTTP.Status = 200 Then
  Set objADOStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
  objADOStream.Open
  objADOStream.Type = 1 'adTypeBinary

  objADOStream.Write objXMLHTTP.ResponseBody
  objADOStream.Position = 0    'Set the stream position to the start

  objADOStream.SaveToFile strHDLocation
  objADOStream.Close
  Set objADOStream = Nothing
End if
```

Note: I should not use any third party apps, so I dont use wget for example.

I made a log file as suggested, result:

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.8
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\AppBackUpTools\ALM\NotifikaceVSE\SLA_Escalation\download_excel\saveGSheet.vbs(27, 3) ADODB.Stream: Write to file failed.
```

Answer (score 0):

modify your **saveGSheet.bat** as below:

```
c:\Windows\SysWOW64\cscript saveGSheet.vbs > %temp%\saveGSheet.log 2>&1
```

after the task is executed, examine the content of the log file at **%temp%\saveGSheet.log** that should give you some clue to debug further

Comment: Thank You, now I know the problem is this: "ADODB.Stream: Write to file failed."

Answer (score -1):

You have no rights to write there. Change the folder ie to the folder where you have vbscript.